# Leibniz formula for successive differentiation proof?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

is there any proof for the Leibniz rule for successive differentiation

$(uv)^{(n)}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{k}{n}u^{(n-k)}v^{(k)}$

Comment: Yes, of course there is.  I think induction, making use of the ordinary Leibniz rule, and Pascal's identity should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use induction, along with the Leibniz rule for first derivative.